# Php preg_match regex for string like 235 12 r12, 212 70 43 etc

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need a preg_match regex for searching the like

123 21 r32 , 329 29 49

basically what i want is the regex would match first 3 occurance of digits and then a space and then 2 digits and then a space then 2 or 3 alphanumeric characters.

#### Code ported from comments:

I have tried `/^[\d{3} \d{2} [0-9,a-z]{2-3}]+$/i` but it doesn't work

Comment: I have tried /^[\d{3} \d{2} [0-9,a-z]{2-3}]+$/i but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Nirmal Ram: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: @NirmalRam: I think you want `()`, not `[]`.

Comment: @minitech: now he will replace **all** `[]` with `()` ;-)

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = '123 21 r32 , 329 29 49';

preg_match_all('/\d{3} \d{2} [a-z\d]{2,3}/i', $string, $matchs);

print_r($matchs[0]);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123 21 r32
    [1] => 329 29 49
)
```

Comment: modified something and got what i exactly need. Thanks cryptic

Comment: You specified searching not matching in your question so my regex searched instead of directly matching. Glad you got it to work out.